# rspec and recaptcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, recaptcha

I'm building tests for a user sign-up page.  I'm about to add Recaptcha to the page, and I don't know how to account for it in rspec.  Specifically, I want my integration test to verify that a user can fill out the page, click on the button, and will be signed up.  But with Recaptcha on the page, how do I get Rspec to simulate entering a valid Recaptcha string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a mock object: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs

There's no point trying to test ReCaptcha, so simulate it.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'm new to rspec and that didn't occur to me.

Comment: No worries, we were all new once!

Comment: could you add an example to this ?

Comment: I know this is old, but the link above is broken.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
context 'User login with captcha' do
  it 'should login with correct recaptcha' do
    LoginController.any_instance.expects(:verify_recaptcha).returns(true)
    user = with_user # get your user...
    post :login, { :username => user.username, :password => user.password }
    session[:user].should eql(user.id)
    response.should redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Recaptcha by default does not verify the captcha in the test environments.

Comment: You can enable it in test environment by `Recaptcha.configuration.skip_verify_env.delete("test")`